# Como dar a elegir la ruta para Guardar PDF?

Tags: c#

Los coloco en contexto, Creo una hoja pdf, le ingreso datos y luego lo guardo en una ruta de mi computadora.

Lo hago de esta manera:

```
Document doc1 = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\...\...\Estado_Cuenta-"+quepolizabusca.Text+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
doc1.Open();
.
.//cuerpo del documento(aqui le escribo todo y coloco tablas)
.
doc1.Close(); //cierro la hoja
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\...\...\Estado_Cuenta-" + quepolizabusca.Text +".pdf");//abro la hoja en pdf
```

El código anterior creo una hoja en una ruta especifica, pero cuando instalo el sistema en otra computadora obviamente no podrá descargar ni abrir el PDF... la pregunta es... Como puedo darle la opción al usuario de que el decida donde quiere guardar el documento PDF.

E intentado hacerlo como cuando exporto un archivo excel... pero no he podido configurarlo o meterlo al codigo del pdf.

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Archivos de Excel|*.xlsx";
saveFileDialog.Title = "Guardar archivo";
saveFileDialog.FileName = "ArchivoExcelCRG";
saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
if (saveFileDialog.FileName != "")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ruta en: " + saveFileDialog.FileName);
    workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
     app.Quit();
     System.Diagnostics.Process Excel = new System.Diagnostics.Process { StartInfo = { FileName = saveFileDialog.FileName } };
     Excel.Start();
}
```

En el codigo anterior si doy a elegir la ruta de guardado pero para una archivo excel.

De ante mano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Archivos de Pdf|*.pdf";
saveFileDialog.Title = "Guardar archivo";
saveFileDialog.FileName = "ArchivoPdfCRG";
saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();

Document doc1 = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    var path = string.Empty;
path = saveFileDialog.Filename;
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
        doc1.Open();
```

Prueba algo así, haces lo mismo pero adaptandolo, o puedes mirar en https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netcore-3.1 donde tienes un ejemplo.
El cambio es sacar la ruta y pasarla